# How to click on the elements which are hidden using laravel dusk?

Tags: laravel-dusk

How to click on the elements which are hidden using laravel dusk? We have script method in selenium. How can we implement the same using Laravel Dusk?

Answer (score 0):

Try
`$browser->script('your js');`

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: You can execute js script in this method. In js get any element and change visibility or click from js. This method just insert js script in page. If page have connect to js-library (like jquery) you can use it